# How to insert data to a table that is connected to a "middletable" which keeps track of two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Basically i need to add songs to a playlist, where the playlist needs to keep track of the consisting songs.

my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Playlist (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    image BLOB,
    private NUMERIC,
    playlistOwner INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(playlistOwner) REFERENCES User(id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    artistName VARCHAR(26),
    genre TEXT, 
    releaseDate DATE
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SongsInPlaylist (
    playlistId INTEGER,
    songId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(playlistId) REFERENCES Playlist(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(songId) REFERENCES Song(id)
)
```

I've tried to join the songsInPlaylist table with the song table when inserting data into the Song table but i'm not succeding. I wonder what the easiest solution would be to be able to read the songs in a specific playlist when requesting for the resource. any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: "I've tried to join the songsInPlaylist table with the song table when inserting data into the Song table" Could you please explain the reason for this? One song can appear in multiple playlists.

Comment: You have `many-to-many` relationship between lists and songs, that you implemented through your 3rd (link) table,  It is very common design so you should not have a problem finding code samples on the Web.